# Why does this function express run despite getting invoked before declaration?

Tags: javascript

I need some clarification.

I'm aware of function declaration getting hoisted to the top of your script in the creation phase, but in my example below I'm creating function expressions.

I don't understand why the function 'CheckAnswer' gets invoked as I invoke the submit event listener before the declaration?

My understanding is the variable will have been created as undefined and when I go to invoke checkAnswer inside the Guess Player function it would throw an error as I don't declare till the end of the file.

Obviously I'm wrong, so some help here would be great :)

```
(function() {
    const playerInput = document.getElementById('player-input');

    // Display player
    const displayPlayer = () => {
        const random = players[Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length)];
    }

    // Player guess
    const playerGuess = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const playerGuess = playerInput.querySelector('input').value;

        checkAnswer(playerGuess);
    }

    playerInput.addEventListener('submit', playerGuess);

    // Check answer
    const checkAnswer = (playerGuess) => {
        console.log(playerGuess);
    }
})();
```

Comment: I was going to say hoisting. But I don't know how it applies here. What is up with `const name = () => {}` rather than `function name() {}`? The arrow function does nothing for readability and its only benefit is an implicit `.bind(this)` which is pointless if the function doesn't use `this`.

Comment: Yeah it's confusing. I thought it might be the arrow functions so I replaced them with function declarations, I also removed the iffy but same issue.

And I was wanted to get in to the habit of using es6 more often, but I'm not sure if it's the right practise here.

Comment: You're not invoking the function before you define it. You're invoking the function when the user clicks the submit button, which is after all this code runs.

Comment: it's really not a good idea to use the same name for functions and variables (playerGuess)

Comment: @Barmar

Oh yeah haha. Silly me! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to actually run `playerGuess(e)` (where `e` is an event created with `new Event(...)`).

You will see that everything works as you would expect & error is raised.

Since in JS functions are the first class citizens, you can (and do in the code) more than one action (invoke) with them.

So, when you write:

```
playerInput.addEventListener('submit', playerGuess);
```

You don't invoke `playerGuess` you just pass it by reference as callback to the event listener, so, it will trigger it once needed.

So, until the user clicks on submit just between you set the event listener & `checkAnswer` is declared, no error will be raised.

Even though, it's quite confusing to read & it certainly would be better to refactor just for sake of saving other people an hour or two of googling.